# Losing image data while converting float32 to ushort

Tags: c++, opencv, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to preview a 16bit pixel array from UE4 in OpenCV.
Each pixel is of type `FFloat16Color` and has 4 variables (RGBA) of type `FFloat`, The FFloat has two relevant parts to it, The `Encoded` (returns a `uint16` variable) and the `GetFloat()` function (returns a `float32`)

Using one of these variables I should be able to create a copy of the image in OpenCV though currently the OpenCV output returns a darkened [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYlLn.jpg).

Using the float value I've tried multiplying by 65535, 65504 and 32768 like so:

```
PixelVal = (ushort)(floatval*multiplier)
```

Using the `encoded` version I receive a "milky" [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBDn7.png)

The `encoded` variable is calculated like so (I think):

```
FORCEINLINE void FFloat16::Set(float FP32Value)
{
    FFloat32 FP32(FP32Value);

    // Copy sign-bit
    Components.Sign = FP32.Components.Sign;

    // Check for zero, denormal or too small value.
    if (FP32.Components.Exponent <= 112)            // Too small exponent? (0+127-15)
    {
        // Set to 0.
        Components.Exponent = 0;
        Components.Mantissa = 0;

         // Exponent unbias the single, then bias the halfp
         const int32 NewExp = FP32.Components.Exponent - 127 + 15;

         if ( (14 - NewExp) <= 24 ) // Mantissa might be non-zero
         {
             uint32 Mantissa = FP32.Components.Mantissa | 0x800000; // Hidden 1 bit
             Components.Mantissa = Mantissa >> (14 - NewExp);
             // Check for rounding
             if ( (Mantissa >> (13 - NewExp)) & 1 )
             {
                 Encoded++; // Round, might overflow into exp bit, but this is OK
             }
         }
    }
    // Check for INF or NaN, or too high value
    else if (FP32.Components.Exponent >= 143)       // Too large exponent? (31+127-15)
    {
        // Set to 65504.0 (max value)
        Components.Exponent = 30;
        Components.Mantissa = 1023;
    }
    // Handle normal number.
    else
    {
        Components.Exponent = int32(FP32.Components.Exponent) - 127 + 15;
        Components.Mantissa = uint16(FP32.Components.Mantissa >> 13);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?
What makes the histogram act like that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the range of initial float values?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?
When I print the float values I get a regular 0-1 values, although some values are weird (4875 or 0.001e78 (not actual prints))

Comment: Then multiplication to USHORT_MAX should work file. Check how do you output the converted image.

Comment: I thought so too, 65535 is the Max value for the short type.
I use CV_16UC4 to initialize the Mat